# Why are my model restrictions ignored?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

here is my model.py :

```
from django.db import models
class Code(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

However when I enter the shell, this returns **no** mistake :

```
In [1]: from mini_url.models import Code

In [2]: co = Code()

In [3]: co.save()

In [4]: co = Code("1234567891011")

In [5]: co.save()
```

Whereas I expect two errors :

1/ from the fact that co is saved without any field, which is supposed to be impossible since there is no `null = True`

2/ from the fact that I save a Code whose`code` field is longer than 10!

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The empty value of a CharField is the empty string `''`.
2. You do not actually set the `code` field. What your are actually doing is setting the id.

   ```
   >>> co = Code("1234567891011")
   >>> co.id
   "1234567891011"
   ```

   Try:

   ```
   co = Code(code="1234567891011")
   co.save()
   ```

   or, if you really do not want to use keyword arguments:

   ```
   co = Code(None, "1234567891011")
   ```

   It will raise an exception if you use a database that enforces length constraints (some databases, [e.g. SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9), don't).

Comment: alright, I get that, but do you know why django allows this? The creation of an object with an argument that is simply lost and replace by an empty one? ( Code(123...) gives <Code : >)

Comment: Moreover I just tried, co = Code(code="1234567891011") raises no exception after a save... and appears in Code.objects.all()

Comment: @VictorSmt you are right about `min_length`, I mixed it up with forms.CharField